# How to create movement from button on google map Android

Tags: java, android

Need to make navigation buttons on the map, can someone tell how to do such a thing, no tutorial on this subject is not found, and as such I do juzat not imagine. Card in the phone led, now you need to add a touch of a button, or go up or down or left or right. Does anyone have any examples? Or at least tell me what event and how to move the map?

Answer (score 0):

The MapView activity itself or the MapView controller has functions to move the map around

Answer (score 0):

```
btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (v == btn4) {
                    GeoPoint p = mapView.getMapCenter();
                    GeoPoint z = new GeoPoint(p.getLatitudeE6(), p.getLongitudeE6() - 1000000);
                    mc.animateTo(z);
                }
            }
        });
```